# Meteor.user() is not waited to load in onBeforeAction using Iron Router RouteController

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to load logged-in user's following users' recipes (like Twitter's home feed).
I'm using Iron-Router RoutController.

I want to query users' following users' recipes in subscription & data like:

```
Recipes.find({
  author: {
    $in: Meteor.user().followings
  }
}, this.findOptions);
```

But 'Meteor.user()' is undefined even though I use 'obBeforeAction'.
So the part `Meteor.subscribe("followingRecipes", Meteor.user().followings, @findOptions())`
and `Recipes.find author: $in: Meteor.user().followings ...` are undefined.

I'm new to Meteor and I need help, please help me, thank you.

My whole code (CoffeeScript): https://github.com/yhagio/re-cip/tree/style2

[lib/router.coffee](https://github.com/yhagio/re-cip/blob/style2/lib/router.coffee)

```
//lib/router.js
FollowingRecipesController = RouteController.extend({
  template: 'followingRecipes',
  increment: 5,
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    if (!Meteor.user()) {
      this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
      if (Meteor.loggingIn()) {
        this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
      } else {
        Router.go('/');
      }
    } else {
      this.next();
    }
  },
  postsLimit: function() {
    return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment;
  },
  findOptions: function() {
    return {
      sort: {
        submitted: -1,
        votes: -1,
        _id: -1
      },
      limit: this.postsLimit()
    };
  },
  subscriptions: function() {
    console.log('subscriptions:', Meteor.user());
    this.recipesSub = Meteor.subscribe("followingRecipes", Meteor.user().followings, this.findOptions());
  },
  recipes: function() {
    console.log('recipes:', Meteor.user());
    Recipes.find({
      author: {
        $in: Meteor.user().followings
      }
    }, this.findOptions);
  },
  nextPath: function() {
    return Router.routes.followingRecipes.path({
      username: this.params.username,
      postsLimit: this.postsLimit() + this.increment
    });
  },
  data: function() {
    var hasMore;
    hasMore = this.recipes().count() === this.postsLimit();
    return {
      recipes: this.recipes(),
      ready: this.recipesSub.ready,
      nextPath: (hasMore ? this.nextPath() : null)
    };
  }
});
```

[server/publications.coffee](https://github.com/yhagio/re-cip/blob/style2/server/publications.coffee)

```
//server/publications.coffee
Meteor.publish('followingRecipes', function(followings, options) {
  return Recipes.find({
    author: {
      $in: followings
    }
  }, options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a coffescript guy but I can try to explain the error a bit

```
    Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() 
   in an onBeforeAction?
```

Go through the readme of iron-router docs

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#migrating-from-094

**From the docs**

onRun and onBeforeAction hooks now require you to call this.next(), and no longer take a pause() argument. So the default behaviour is reversed. For example, if you had:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function(pause) {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('login');
    pause();
  }
});
```

You'll need to update it to

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('login');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

That means wherever you've onBeforeAction function, If you want to proceed to the flow,like you want to run hooks(action,onAfterAction) after checking user is logged in you need to write `this.next()` to continue with the flow

**Ex code**

```
 Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
      if (! Meteor.user()) {
        this.render('login');
      } else {
        this.next();
      }
    });
```

In the above code, If the user is loggedin, the flow will be continued and executes next functions like action,data,onAfetrAction otherwise it will render login template

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I already defined the next(), so this isn't the issue. I'm still investigating and rewrite some.

Answer (score 1):

Is it because the user collection is not yet known to the client ?
Subscribe to the client in a waitOn function.

Something like:

```
  this.route('myaccount',{
    waitOn: function() {
      Meteor.subscribe('experts-all'); // users
    },
    onBeforeAction: function () {
      if (!Meteor.user()) {
        Router.go('signin');
      }
      else this.next();
    },
    template: 'myAccount',
  });
```